# Spooky Action at a Distance: Electron & React useEffect - Unable to unsubscribe from ipcRenderer events

Tags: reactjs, electron, ipcrenderer

I have encountered strange behavior when using Electron's `ipcRenderer` with React's `useEffect`.
Within my electron app, I have the following code:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
const electron = window.require('electron');
const ipcRenderer = electron.ipcRenderer;

...

const someValueThatChanges = props.someValue;

useEffect(() => {
  const myEventName = 'some-event-name';
  console.log(`Using effect. There are currently ${ipcRenderer.listenerCount(eventName)} listeners.`);
  console.log(`Value that has changed: ${someValueThatChanges}.`);
  ipcRenderer.addListener(myEventName, myEventHandler);
  console.log('Added a new listener.');
  // Should clean up the effect (remove the listener) when the effect is called again.
  return () => {
    ipcRenderer.removeListener(myEventName, myEventHandler)
    console.log('Cleaned up event handler.');
  }
}, [ someValueThatChanges ]);

function myEventHandler() {
  console.log('Handled event');
}
```

The code above is supposed to listen to the `some-event-name` event fired by Electron's main process with `mainWindow.webContents.send('some-event-name');` and `console.log(...)` a message inicating that the event was handled.

This works as expected when the effect is initially run. A listener is added, the event is raised at a later time, and the string `'Handled event'` is printed to to the console. But when the `someValueThatChanges` variable is assigned a different value and  the event is raised for a second time, the 'Handled event' string is printed out to the console *twice* (the old listener does not appear to have been removed).

The line with the `listenerCount(eventName)` call returns 0 as expected when the `removeListener(...)` call is included in the useEffect return/cleanup function. When the `removeListener(...)` call is removed, the `listenerCount(eventName)` call returns a value that is incremented as expected (e.g. 0, 1, 2) as listeners are not removed.

Here's the really weird part. In *either* case, whether or not I include the call to `removeListener(...)`, the `myEventHandler` function is always called for as many times as useEffect has been run. In other words, Electron reports that there are no event listeners, but `myEventHandler` still seems to be called by the previous listeners. Is this a bug in Electron, or am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe try with `on()` instead of `addListener()`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried both. According to the NodeJs docs which define `EventEmitter`, `on` and `off` are aliases for `addListener` and `removeListener` respectively: https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_addlistener_eventname_listener. Which brings up another weird thing: the Electron ipcRenderer API doesn't quite match the NodeJS EventEmitter API. Just enough to be annoying.

Comment: As an example, ipcRenderer supports `on()` but not `off()`, and `removeListener()` but not `addListener()`. The NodeJS API supports all four. That said, neither of the four functions, when used on `IpcRenderer`, throw any errors. So either `off` and `addListener` are supported in Electron but not documented, or they aren't supported and fail silently.

Comment: I've created a feature request on the Electron repo to standardize the ipcRenderer API/update its documentation. My issue here remains unresolved, but for those who are interested: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/22129

Comment: Did you ever fix this? I've got the same issue and it's driving me nuts. I've even tried: `ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners('channel-name')` at the start of the useEffect to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Never try with `ipcRenderer.addListener`, But try `ipcRenderer.on` instead

```
useEffect(() => {
  ipcRenderer.send('send-command', 'ping');

  ipcRenderer.on('get-command', (event, data) => {
    console.log('data', data);
  });

  return () => {
    ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners('get-command');
  };
}, []);
```

I believe, the docs changed. `ipcRenderer.removeAllListeners` accept single string instead of array of string Source [electron issues](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/10379),